# Testing and comparing query performance with MonetDB

Tags: monetdb

I'm trying to run some tests on query times and would like to know if there is a way to turn off caching so data is read from disk every time instead of memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MonetDB uses memory-mapped files. The contents of these files are cached by the OS in the page cache, which in Linux will use any free memory. What I do to get fair 'cold' runs (force data being read from dist} is to

1. Stop the database
2. Clear file system caches. On Linux, run the following command: `sudo bash -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"` (See the [Kernel doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt) for details)
3. Start the database again and run your query

Generally, there will be more fluctuation in performance results than if the data is in memory, so I recommend you to repeat this a couple of times to get consistent readings.

There is a [benchmark script](https://github.com/MonetDB/monetdb-postgres-compare/blob/master/ehannes.sh) (`ehannes.sh`) that automates much of the process for you.